# TypeORM WHERE condition fails on column selected by addSelect

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

I am selecting some calculated value from a table that I just joined,

```
query.addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(invoice.amount / 100), 0)', 'depositAmount');
```

it works just fine, but if I want to do this

```
query.andWhere('"depositAmount" >= :depositAmountFrom', { depositAmountFrom: 100 });
```

it fails with error `column "depositAmount" does not exist`.
Whats strange about this, is that later I am doing

```
query.sortBy('"depositAmount"', 'DESC');
```

and it works fine. Why can't I use that column in andWhere then?

Comment: I don't think that `'depositAmount'` and `'"depositAmount"'` is the same. What happens if you remove the double quotes or add them where they are missing?

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis without doublequotes, Postgres casts column name to lowercase, and I still got the same error `column "depositamount" does not exist`. Adding it to the addSelect alias causes syntax error

Comment: Then another thing is that you cannot use alias in the `WHERE` clause. I think you have to repeat the formula.

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis unfortunately I can't, because then I am getting `aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

Comment: Is this the only field you are selecting?

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis I am selecting from user table
     `this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')`, and then joining it's relation
     `query.leftJoin(Invoice,'invoice','invoice."userId" = user.id AND invoice.type = :type AND invoice.status = :status', { type: InvoiceTypeEnum.TYPE_DEPOSIT, status: InvoiceStatusEnum.STATUS_DONE },
    );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237093/discussion-between-reinis-verbelis-and--).